# What does "charge" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> "The soft smile they traded left him with a pleasant, lingering
> **charge**."

Does it mean "feeling" or "emotion"?

Comment: It uses the metaphor of an electrical charge to imply a feeling.

Answer (score 1):

Yes @Kate Bunting is probably right.

I found this definition in Google

charge
/tʃɑːdʒ/

noun
noun: charge; plural noun: charges

4. The property of matter that is responsible for electrical phenomena, existing in a positive or negative form.

[... ...]

INFORMAL
a thrill.
"I get a real charge out of working hard"

Hence, yes, this term means "feeling" or "emotion", as you suggested, but in a deeper, more intense way.